# How to create unit tests for .cpp files in a different project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently using Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++ and have been following this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019

However, when trying to create a test project under the same solution as the project I am testing I can't I keep getting the linker error

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl SLL<int>::add(int)" (?add@?$SLL@H@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl A1272UnitTest::A1272UnitTest::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@A1272UnitTest@1@QEAAXXZ)
```

The problem I am trying to use a method definition inside of the "q1a.cpp" file under the project I am testing.

I have tried following this guide 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-microsoft-test-framework-for-cpp?view=vs-2019#object_files

In order to link the obj files but it was of no avail.

This is what my
[solution directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9teY.png) looks like

Comment: Are you other project a library or executable? (should be a library, so you can link with it.) so typically, you have libraries, application (linked to libraries) which mainly is just the main and call the main library function, and a test application (possibly by library) (linked to libraries too and to the test-framework) which does the test.

Comment: It's an application. So I guess I have to make a library.